# gspread: 'Connection aborted.', error(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host'

Tags: python, oauth, gspread

I am using gspread and python. My code was working fine and I made no changes and I started receiving this error: 'Connection aborted.', error(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host' My script started running for shorter and shorter time periods until now where it will not run at all. Here is how I am trying to authenticate.

```
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds']
creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('QSIO-
722b2a587942.json', scope)
client = gspread.authorize(creds)

sheet=client.open("1718ps_onice_nst").sheet1
```

After reading some other posts, I also tried to add client.login() after client = gspread.authorize(creds). I also tried creating a new project with new credentials and that did not work either.

Comment: Hello. I've encountered the same error with you.
Did you solved that problem?
If did, plz share the experience.
Thank you.